# Writing a method that lets an arraylist accept and store objects

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

I'm writing a class and I need to write a class where the arraylist accept and stores an object of its type. I know this is probably extremely simple but I'm running on no sleep. Here is my Stock Manager class

```
public class StockManager {

private String appleStocks;
private ArrayList<StockRecord> myList;

public StockManager(String appleStocks) {
    this.appleStocks = appleStocks;
    this.myList = new ArrayList<StockRecord>();
}

public void addStock() {
    for (StockRecord aRecord : this.myList) {
        this.myList.add(aRecord);
    }
}
```

If you need to see my other class I can supply it but I don't think it would be necessary

Comment: I need to know what to write in the addStock() method.

Comment: why are you using for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is reading over the list and adding each element back. Try this instead. get a new element as method argument and add to the list

```
public void addStock(StockRecord stock) {
    myList.add(stock);
}
```

Comment: Mark it as correct, if it answers your question :-)

Comment: I would but it still has a time limit on it. 3 more minutes :P

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addStock(StockRecord record) 
{
    if(record != null)
    {
            this.myList.add(record);
    }
}
```

Just pass a stock record to the class and add it from the inside.  If it's null then it will skip the if statement.  Easy.